# Boto unable to fetch ElasticSearch Cloudwatch metrics

Tags: boto, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get elasticsearch cloud-watch metrics using boto but whatever I do, I do not get the value. Below is snippet of my code , same code works for example if I use for RDS metrics.

```
import datetime
import boto.ec2.cloudwatch

end = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
start = end - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

metric="CPUUtilization"

region = boto.regioninfo.RegionInfo(
    name='ap-southeast-1',
    endpoint='monitoring.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com')

conn = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.CloudWatchConnection(region=region)

data = conn.get_metric_statistics(60, start, end, metric, "AWS/ES", "Average", {"DomainName": "My-es-name"})
```

> print data
>
> []

However if I change the namespace to RDS it works fine with proper dimension value. This is a simple code which I can write. I am not sure what is wrong here. Can anyone help me to figure out this?

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution.

To pull Elasticsearch metrics for a specific domain name, you need to also indicate your ClientId in the dimensions.

My examples below are in Boto3, but for executing it with your code (boto2), I believe you only need to amend the dimensions as follow, assuming your syntax was originally right:

```
data = conn.get_metric_statistics(60, start, end, metric, "AWS/ES", "Average", {"ClientId":"My-client-id", "DomainName": "My-es-name"})
```

Try the code below (boto3). It worked for me.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

cloudwatch = boto3.resource('cloudwatch', region_name='ap-southeast-1')
cpu = cloudwatch.Metric('AWS/ES', 'CPUUtilization')

cpu_usage = cpu.get_statistics(
    Dimensions=[
        {'Name': 'ClientId', 'Value': 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID'},
        {'Name': 'DomainName', 'Value': 'YOUR-DOMAIN-NAME'}
    ],
    StartTime=(datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=5)).isoformat(),
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
    Period=60,
    Statistics=['Average']
)
```

If you prefer to use a client, use the following instead:

```
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='ap-southeast-1')
response = client.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/ES',
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    Dimensions=[
        {'Name': 'ClientId', 'Value': 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID'},
        {'Name': 'DomainName', 'Value': 'YOUR-DOMAIN-NAME'}
    ],
    StartTime=(datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=5)).isoformat(),
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
    Period=60,
    Statistics=['Average']
)
```

Comment: Let me check.. moving to boto3 is bit difficult for me as I have to move all my code to boto3.

Comment: It should work just the same with Boto syntax. Let me update my answer with what I think would work with your code.

Comment: Lifesaver.. applies for the CLI also.